# как передать tableadapter с одной формы в другую?

Tags: c#, datagrid

Всем привет! пишу собственный проект для облегчения некоторых моментов на работе(не программирование). C# EF,бд MS SQL Server. Есть таблица datagrid. Для редактирования данных
и охранения их таблице и бд использовал следующий код :

```
if (datagrid.SelectRows.Count > 0)
{
    peopleBindingSource.EndEdit();
    this.peopleTableAdapter.Update(this.comissiaDataSetDb.People);
}
```

Сперва редактирование происходило в той же форме где и таблица и все прекрасно работало. Изменения и в таблице и бд.Но переделал и редактирование и обновления добавляются теперь в другой форме. Как мне теперь вызвать peopleTableAdapter.Update(this.comissiaDataSetDb.People); ??? сделать публичным метод не очень хорошая идея, нарушая инкапсуляцию.
Пробовал передать объект СomissiaDataSetDb, вообще пишет при открытии второй null(в полях для ввода отображались данные текущие выделенной строки с datagrid). Без передачи объект СomissiaDataSetDb данные заполняют поля для ввода и все ок. Мозг сломал уже второй вечер
Кто, что подскажет?
Извиняюсь, первый раз пишу вопрос)

Comment: WPF? Winforms?.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Передавайте все зависимости в конструкторе формы.

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось все проще! Можно лишь вызвать `datagridview.Update();`

Не нужно никакой `tableadapter` вызывать.
А чтобы изменения принялись и в бд можно сделать так :

```
var persoтHaus = context.StatusUserInfos.Where(i => i.PersonId.Equals(person.Id)).FirstOrDefault();
context.StatusUserInfos.Attach(personHaus);
datagridview.Update();
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov `C# EF,бд MS SQL Server.`